# regex sub different string of same length

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings that I want to parse to extract the operator, but there may also be operators within quoted substrings that I want to ignore. In each string, there would only be one operator (==, !=, <, <=, >, >=) that is not within quotes.

Some Examples:

```
s1 = "'x > 1' == 2"
s2 = "'<Age>'<=32"
s3 = 'name == ""type<3>""'
```

I tried using `re.sub('[\'"]+(.*?)[\'"]+', r'', s1)` to replace any quoted material with nothing. This allows me to find the operator each time, but then I can't find the position of the operator. Is there a way to sub whitespace of the same length as the string that is being subbed? I'd like them to look like they do below so I can use `re.search` and then split at the operator.

```
s1 = "        ==  "
s2 = "       <=32"
s3 = 'name ==            '
```

Is this possible, or is there another approach I can take to this?

Answer (score -1):

The replacement can be a function, which receives the match as an argument. It can then return a string with the appropriate number of spaces.

```
re.sub(r'[\'"]+(.*?)[\'"]+', lambda m: " " * len(m.group(0)), s1)
```